# Set only one node (root) note to be draggable in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, draggable, force-layout

I'm working on a d3 force layout graph, with looks pretty like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130).
What I want is the root node to be fixed not draggable. I fixed the root node in the json file by adding

```
"fixed": true
```

but it is still draggable. In my JS file there is the code

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);
```

If I remove the last line of this code, the whole graph isn't draggable anymore. I think 'force' is a global variable and determines, that the whole graph is draggable. But I want only the root node not to be draggable and the should be draggable. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have an example ? I have tested this in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LtYnU/8/ notice in the loop i set the first one to fixed. This works fine ?

Comment: In your example, the nodes are not draggable. Add .call(force.drag) in the last line of your code. Then all nodes are draggable and you can move them with your mouse. I want only the root node to be not-draggable and the rest to be draggable. Is it clear what I mean?

Comment: oh i see, give me a second :)

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the drag event from the node you wish to stay fixed.

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/qvco2Ljy/112/

I have looped through the data to give the first element a fixed attribute and also a donotmove attribute as when you drag and let go, perhaps you want the node to stay fixed (for children i mean), so using d.fixed here will cause a conflict :

```
graph.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.donotmove = false;
  if (i == 0) {d.donotmove = true; d.fixed = true;}
})
```

And when calling drag events, check for the donotmove attribute like so :

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .on("dragstart", function(d) {

    if (d.donotmove) return;
    dragstarted(d)
  })
  .on("drag", function(d) {

    if (d.donotmove) return;
    dragged(d)
  })
  .on("dragend", function(d) {

    if (d.donotmove) return;
    dragended(d)
  })
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I would parse the data when you start, i.e loop through, check if d.fixed == true; if it is, set d.donotmove to true; and then use that value as the check to stop conflicts